# Find specific value in 2nd row and display value from 3rd row

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm just learning mysql so this is probably super easy.

I have a table with 3 rows with the following sample data

```
user_id    metakey       meta_value
  1        image_type    avatar
  1        location      london
  1        image_url     1.jpg
  2        image_type    facebook
  2        location      somewhere
  2        image_url
```

How do I get the values of `meta_value` without re-querying the table every single time  if I want the `meta_value` data from another `metakey` ?

So 1->location would display london 2->image_type would display facebook and so on.

With a bit of fiddling around I ended up here:

```
$query_usermeta = "SELECT * FROM usermeta WHERE user_id = '$user_id'" or die("Error in the consult.." . mysqli_error($link));
//execute the query.
$result_usermeta = mysqli_query($link, $query_usermeta);
/* associative array */
$userdatameta = $result_usermeta->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

then going for `echo $userdatameta['meta_value']`  but how do I specify which meta_value to display?

I know I can do this in the mysql query like `WHERE metakey = 'location'` but then I would have to query it many times to get all the values, no ?

Comment: Oh, the joys of the Entity-Attribute-Value model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of running queries for each row just build your array as key value pairs,query by only user id

`SELECT * FROM usermeta WHERE user_id = '$user_id'`

Loop over your results

```
$metaData=array();

while($row = $result_usermeta->fetch_array())
{
$metaData[$row['metakey']] = $row['meta_value'];
}
```

Now in `$metaData` you have values as key value pair as

```
array(
    'image_type'=>'avatar',
    'location' =>'london',
    'image_url'=>'1.jpg'
)
```

Now use your values as for location `echo $metaData['location']` for image url `echo $metaData['image_url']`

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it would be to do a pivot, so that the metakeys become the returned column names.

```
SELECT user_id,
       CASE WHEN metakey = 'image_type' THEN meta_value END as image_type,
       CASE WHEN metakey = 'location' THEN meta_value END as location,
       CASE WHEN metakey = 'image_url' THEN meta_value END as image_url
FROM usermeta 
WHERE user_id = '$user_id'
```

Then you can select the meta_value by the metakey

```
echo $userdatameta['location']
```